# Подскажите код который может призвать в программу алфавит кириллицу

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
l = ["001000", "000001", "011001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "001011", "000000", "000011", "000001", "001101", "000000", "001110", "000001", "000000", "001011", "001111", "010001", "000001", "000010", "001100", "011110", "000000", "001111", "000101", "001111", "001100", "000111", "001001", "010011", "011110", "000000", "001110", "000110", "001101", "001110", "001111", "000100", "001111", "000000", "000100", "001111", "010001", "100000", "011000", "000110", "000100", "001111", "000000", "010010", "001111", "000111", "000001", "001100", "000110", "000110", "001101", "000000", "011000", "010011", "001111", "000000", "000011", "000001", "001101", "000000", "001110", "000110", "000000", "011011", "000011", "000001", "010011", "001001", "010011", "000000", "001110", "000001", "000000", "001111", "000010", "010001", "000001", "010011", "001110", "011101", "001010", "000000", "010000", "010100", "010011", "011110", "000000", "001101", "011101", "000000", "010000", "010001", "001001", "001011", "001001", "001110", "010100", "001100", "001001", "000000", "011000", "010011", "001111", "000000", "000101", "001111", "000000", "010000", "001111", "100001", "010010", "000001", "000000", "000001", "010010", "010011", "000110", "010001", "001111", "001001", "000101", "001111", "000011", "000000", "000011", "000001", "001101", "000000", "000101", "001111", "001100", "000111", "001110", "001111", "000000", "011011", "000011", "000001", "010011", "001001", "010011", "011110", "000000", "000001", "000000", "010000", "001111", "010011", "001111", "001101", "000000", "001100", "001111", "000111", "001001", "010011", "000110", "010010", "011110", "000000", "000011", "000000", "000101", "010001", "000110", "001010", "010101", "000000", "001001", "000000", "000011", "011101", "001000", "011101", "000011", "000001", "001010", "010011", "000110", "000000", "000001", "000011", "000001", "010001", "001001", "001010", "001110", "011101", "001010", "000000", "001011", "001111", "010001", "000001", "000010", "001100", "011110", "000000", "010010", "000000", "010011", "001001", "010011", "000001", "001110", "000001", "000000", "010010", "010000", "000001", "010010", "001001", "000010", "001111", "000000", "001000", "000001", "000000", "010010", "001111", "010011", "010001", "010100", "000101", "001110", "001001", "011000", "000110", "010010", "010011", "000011", "001111", "000000", "000001", "001100", "001100", "001111", "000000", "011111", "010011", "001111", "000000", "010001", "000001", "000101", "001001", "010010", "010011", "000000", "001011", "001111", "010001", "000001", "000010", "001100", "100001", "000000", "100001", "001110", "000000", "010011", "001111", "001100", "011110", "001011", "001111", "000000", "011000", "010011", "001111", "000000", "001111", "010011", "010010", "100000", "000101", "000001", "000000", "010100", "011001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "000100", "001001", "000100", "000001", "001110", "010011", "010010", "001011", "001001", "000110", "000000", "010010", "001100", "001001", "001000", "001110", "001001", "000000", "010010", "001111", "000000", "011010", "010100", "010000", "000001", "001100", "011110", "010111", "000001", "001101", "001001", "000000", "010000", "001111", "100001", "000011", "001001", "001100", "001001", "010010", "011110", "000000", "001110", "000001", "000000", "001011", "001111", "010001", "000001", "000010", "001100", "000110", "000000", "000101", "000110", "010010", "100001", "010011", "011110", "000000", "001101", "001001", "001110", "010100", "010011", "000000", "001110", "000001", "001000", "000001", "000101", "000000", "010000", "010001", "001001", "010010", "010011", "011101", "001011", "001111", "000011", "000001", "001100", "001001", "010010", "011110", "000000", "001011", "000000", "001110", "000001", "001101", "000000", "010000", "000001", "010001", "000001", "001100", "001001", "001000", "001111", "000011", "000001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "011001", "010011", "010100", "010001", "001101", "000001", "001110", "000001", "000000", "001011", "000001", "001011", "001111", "001010", "000000", "010011", "001111", "000000", "011001", "010011", "010100", "001011", "001111", "001010", "000000", "000011", "010001", "001111", "000101", "000110", "000000", "001111", "000100", "010001", "001111", "001101", "001110", "001111", "000100", "001111", "000000", "010000", "001111", "001110", "011000", "001001", "001011", "000001", "000000", "010010", "000000", "001100", "010100", "011000", "000001", "001101", "001001", "000000", "001111", "010010", "010011", "000001", "001100", "011110", "001110", "011101", "001101", "000000", "010000", "010001", "001001", "001011", "000001", "001000", "000001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "001110", "000110", "000000", "000101", "000011", "001001", "000100", "000001", "010011", "011110", "010010", "100001", "000000", "010000", "000110", "010001", "000110", "000100", "010001", "010100", "001000", "001001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "010000", "001111", "011000", "010011", "001001", "000000", "000011", "010010", "000110", "000000", "001011", "001111", "001110", "010011", "000110", "001010", "001110", "000110", "010001", "011101", "000000", "010010", "000000", "010011", "001111", "010000", "001100", "001001", "000011", "001111", "001101", "000000", "001110", "000001", "000000", "010010", "000011", "001111", "001010", "000000", "001011", "001111", "010001", "000001", "000010", "001100", "011110", "000000", "001111", "010010", "010011", "000001", "000011", "001001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "010000", "000001", "011000", "001011", "010100", "000000", "001011", "000001", "001000", "000001", "011011", "010010", "010011", "000001", "001110", "010010", "001011", "001001", "011011", "000000", "000101", "000110", "001110", "000110", "000100", "000000", "001001", "000000", "010100", "001100", "000110", "010011", "000110", "001100", "001001", "000000", "001011", "010011", "001111", "000000", "001001", "001101", "000000", "000101", "000001", "001100", "000000", "010000", "010001", "000001", "000011", "001111", "000000", "010011", "000001", "001011", "000000", "010010", "000110", "000010", "100001", "000000", "000011", "000110", "010010", "010011", "001001", "000000", "001001", "000000", "001111", "010011", "001011", "010100", "000101", "000001", "000000", "001111", "001110", "001001", "000000", "001000", "001110", "000001", "100000", "010011", "000000", "011000", "010011", "001111", "000000", "010100", "000000", "001110", "000001", "010010", "000000", "010010", "010011", "000001", "001110", "010111", "001001", "100001", "000000", "001110", "000001", "000000", "010011", "001001", "010011", "000001", "001110", "000110", "000000", "001110", "010100", "000111", "001110", "001111", "000000", "010011", "001111", "010000", "001100", "001001", "000011", "001111", "000000", "000101", "001111", "000010", "010001", "000001", "010011", "011110", "010010", "100001", "000000", "000101", "001111", "000000", "001100", "010100", "001110", "001110", "001111", "001010", "000000", "010010", "010011", "000001", "001110", "010111", "001001", "001001", "000000", "001110", "001111", "001101", "000110", "010001", "000000", "000011", "001111", "010010", "000110", "001101", "011110", "000000", "001011", "000001", "001011", "000000", "010011", "000001", "001101", "000000", "010010", "011101", "000100", "010001", "000001", "001100", "000000", "010001", "000110", "000001", "001100", "000000", "010000", "010001", "001111", "010011", "001001", "000011", "000000", "010000", "010010", "000111"] 
b = []
i = 0
print("")
k = {0: " ",1: "а",2: "б",3: "в",4: "г",5: "д",6: "е",7: "ж",8: "з",9: "и",10: "й",11: "к",12: "л",13: "м",14: "н",15: "о",16: "п",17: "р",18: "с",19: "т",20: "у",21: "ф",22: "х",23: "ц",24: "ч",25: "ш",26: "щ",27: "ъ",28: "ы",29: "ь",30: "э",31: "ю",32: "я"} 
translated  = [] 
kk = k.keys()


while i < len(l): 
 b.append(int(l[i],2)) 
 i += 1 

print("Encrypted message: " + str(b))  
print("") 
print("") 
print("Lenght of the message: " + str(len(b))) 


m = 0
j = 0 



while j < len(b): 
 while m < len(kk): 
  if b[j] == kk[m]:  
   translated.append(k[m].decode('utf-8'))
  m += 1 
 m = 0
j += 1 


print("")   
print("".join(translated))
```

Comment: Судя по `print`'ам это не питон 2.7, либо не все импорты показаны. А диапазон букв легко получить: `[chr(i) for i in range(ord('а'), ord('я') + 1)]` только в него `ё` не входит, поэтому ее нужно вручную добавлять. А так я бы не стал с кодом парится и просто вбил бы алфавит в список или строку

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буква ё мне не нужна. Просто я можно сказать новичок в Python'e.

Comment: Если вас устроил мой комментарий, я оформлю его как ответ

Answer (score 3):

Для получения диапазона букв можно использовать код:

```
cyrillic = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('а'), ord('я') + 1)]
print(cyrillic)  # ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я']

cyrillic_str = ''.join(cyrillic)
print(cyrillic_str)  # 'абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
```

Однако буква **ё** в тот диапазон не входит, поэтому ее нужно будет добавить вручную.

---

Но самый простой способ – вручную забить:

```
cyrillic_str_lower = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
cyrillic_str_upper = lower.upper()
```